# The function takes two arguments: Prompt: str and Return types: int, float, str

Tags: python, prompt

Hello everyone I need some help with this question

Write a function named safe_input (prompt, type)
that works like the Python input function,
except that it only accepts the specified type of input.

The function takes two arguments:

prompt: str

Type: int, float, str

The function will keep prompting for input until correct input of the specified type is
entered. The function returns the input. If the input was specified to be a number (float or int), the value returned will be of the correct type; that is,the function will perform the conversion.

The default for a prompt is the empty string.
The default for the type is string.

## Heres what I have:

```
safe_input = input(str("Enter a String Type you want to check: "))

test = safe_input("this is a string")
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input("this is a string",int)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input("this is a string",float)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))                       
test = safe_input(5)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input(5,int)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input(5,float)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input(5.044)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input(5.044, int)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))
test = safe_input(5.044, float)
print ('"{}" is a {}'.format(test,type(test)))

def safe_input (prompt, type=str):

    if (type == int):
        while (True):
           try:
            # check for integer or float
            integer_check = int(prompt)
            # If integer, numbers will be equal
            if (prompt == integer_check):
                return integer_check
            else:
                print("They are not equal!!")
                return integer_check
        except ValueError:
            print ("Your entry, {}, is not of {}."
                   .format(prompt,type))
            prompt = input("Please enter a variable of the type '{}': "
                           .format(type))
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? My friend and I been working on this for hours.

### UPDATE: I get errors such as:

```
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\ei8069_Lab9_Q4.py", line 28, in <module>
       test = safe_input("this is a string")
  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\ei8069_Lab9_Q4.py", line 28, in <module>
       test = safe_input("this is a string")
  TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is currently wrong with your code? (What incorrect behavior is it exhibiting?)

Comment: On your first line you assign the value of safe_input to a user-entered value, and then call it as if it is a function! Define the safe_input function first, and the input() call should be inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents.

First, read your assignment more carefully, your method isn't exactly what they want.

And you are using a lot of unnecessary conditions. Your function could be much more simplier, like this:

```
def safe_input(prompt, type_=str):
    if(type_ not in (str, int, float)): 
        raise ValueError("Expected str, int or float.")  

    while True:
        test = input(prompt)    
        try:
            ret = type_(test)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid type, enter again.")                
        else:
            break    

    return ret
```

Try not to use builtin functions like type for variable names. They would override builtins and can cause a lot of headache later on.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have this line:

```
safe_input = input(str("Enter a String Type you want to check: "))
```

At the beginning of your program. You should have the definition of the function instead, but you have it at the end.

**Solution**: remove that bogus line and move the definition of the function to the top of the program.

**Explanation**: When you run that line, it will ask the user for something, and that (say `42` will be assigned to `safe_input`. Then you try to use that as a function, but hey, `42` is an integer, and that cannot be called.

Comment: I see so it was right for the most part just the position of the user input and define the safe_input function first Thanks guys!!